# How to publish more than one picture on Twitter with PHP

Tags: php, image, api, twitter

I already know how to publish a picture with PHP on my twitter account. I use twitteroauth and it works fine with this code.

```
$with_media = '';
$texte = ltrim(rtrim($line["texte"]));

if($line["image"] > 0) { 
    $image = strval($line["image"]);
    $file = 'twitpic/' . $image . '.jpg';   // this is path of local file
    $type = 'jpg';      // jpg
    $name = $image . '.jpg'; // image.jpg
    $media = '@' . realpath($file) . ';type=image/' . $type . ';filename=' . $name;
    $with_media = '_with_media';
}

$status = $texte . ' - ' . $turl;
$params = array('media[]' => $media, 'status' => $status);
$code = $tmhOAuth->request( 'POST', 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update' . $with_media . '.json', $params, true, true); // use_auth and multipart
```

Ok.. May be it's not the best coding.. but it works.

So, now, after many tries, I try to figure myself how to publish up to 3 pictures at the same time. Tried many different things, but never succeed. I don't even know if it's possible.

Anyone could help ? And may be explain how to publish .GIF the same way ?

Thanks a lot.

FZ

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [deprecated API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update_with_media) - the `update_with_media` option is no longer supported.

[According to the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/media), here is what you have to do.

1. [Upload an image to Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload)
2. Get a `media_id_string` in response.
3. Repeat for up to 4 images.
4. Use [`statuses/update`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update) to create your tweet - with the parameter `media_ids` set to the IDs of the uploaded images.

That will let you post multiple still images to Twitter. You can only post one GIF or Video at a time though.

Comment: Ok. Thank you Terence, for your reply. It's not for me. English is not my first language and it's quite impossible for me to understand Twitter documentation. Too complex and not enough examples.